# MySql IF in WHERE query when a column has negative and positive values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query like

```
SELECT SUM(a.payment_value) AS paymentvalue 
FROM tableA a 
WHERE IF (a.column_3 <> 'UOB' AND a.column_3 <> 'Affin', 
  a.payment_value > 0, 
 {else a.payment_value can be positive and negative value}) 
GROUP BY a.column_3;
```

The query is to

1. sum column a.payment_value Group by `a.column_3`
2. condition 1, `if a.column_3 is not 'UOB' or 'AFFIN'`, select and only sum positive value
3. condition 2, `if a.column_3 is UOB' or 'AFFIN'`, select and sum positive and negative values

I tried the following (supposedly to sum 2 lines -> 1000 + (-5) = 995) but returns only -5 as the paymentvalue and not the summed.

```
SELECT SUM(a.payment_value) AS paymentvalue 
FROM tableA a 
WHERE IF (a.column_3 <> 'UOB' AND a.column_3 <> 'Affin', a.payment_value > 0, a.payment_value > 0 OR a.payment_value > 0) 
GROUP BY a.column_3;
```

How should I write the IF in WHERE clause with these conditions?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team leader had solved this problem and here I would like to share the solution with all. The code is

```
SELECT SUM(a.payment_value) AS paymentvalue FROM tableA a WHERE IF (a.column_3 <> 'UOB' AND a.column_3 <> 'Affin', a.payment_value > 0, a.payment_value) GROUP BY a.column_3;
```

will simply grab any value (positive or negative) in a.payment_value column if the conditions are not met.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to approach it (there are multiple ways to do it).  In my recommendation below, I create tags for each of the 2 conditions you described, as well as a third condition to capture everything else just in case.

Then, I wrap it into a sub-query and sum payment_value from the sub-query, while grouping on conditions to differentiate each condition.

I hope it helps you:

```
SELECT
    sub.Conditions
    ,SUM(sub.payment_value) paymentValue
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *
        ,CASE
            WHEN a.column_3 NOT IN ('UOB','AFFIN') AND a.payment_value > 0 THEN 'Condition1'
            WHEN a.column_3 IN ('UOB','AFFIN') THEN 'Condition2'
            ELSE 'Condition3'
        END Conditions
    FROM TableA a
    ) sub
GROUP BY
    sub.Conditions;
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. I may need the above in future, when my code gets more complicated :)

Comment: Hi @lazyduckiy.. if the above provides a solution to your question, can you please mark it as answered or give it a plus/up check?  It should provide a way to get the answer you are looking for.